# Pods Advanced Content types Templates

Tags: wordpress, routes, pods-framework

I'm attempting to utilize Advanced Content Types (ACT) in Pods, but I'm facing challenges in finding resources for creating listing and single templates. Has anyone created something similar?

Additionally, I'm working on establishing relationship fields between multiple ACTs. However, the relationship column doesn't seem to appear in any of the wp_pods_{act} tables. What steps should I take to address this issue?